# Escape keypress event in Java JDK 8

Tags: java

Can someone please inform me if there is a way to capture the Escape keypress event in Java JDK 8 without utilizing Swing and AWT related libraries or without the need for additional external libraries? I am working in a console environment.

```
package test;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
int input;
do {
input = System.in.read();
char character = (char) input;
if (input == 27) {
break;
}
System.out.println("Press " + character);
} while (true);
}
}
```